# Swift enum with default protocol implementation

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have multiple Core Data-related enums like:

```
enum ManagedItemProperties: String {
    case purchaseDate
    case productId
    case addons
}
```

I want to have a protocol for each of these enums to generate a `NSSortDescriptor` and `NSPredicate`s for fetching objects by their properties.

Is it possible to write a protocol like:

```
protocol ManagedProperty {
    func sortDescriptor(ascending: Bool) -> NSSortDescriptor
    func predicateEqual(to arg: CVarArg) -> NSPredicate
    func predicate(_ booleanValue: Bool) -> NSPredicate
}
```

And its default implementation similar to this:

```
extension ManagedProperty where ????? {
    func sortDescriptor(ascending: Bool = true) -> NSSortDescriptor {
        return NSSortDescriptor(key: ?????, ascending: ascending)
    }
    func predicateEqual(to arg: CVarArg) -> NSPredicate {
        return NSPredicate(format: "SELF.%@ == %@", ?????, arg)
    }
    func predicate(_ booleanValue: Bool) -> NSPredicate {
        return NSPredicate(format: "SELF.%@ == %d", ?????, booleanValue)
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are doing something wrong in your design or overcomplicating it if you need to have the attributes of your Core Data entities as enums.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Maybe it's actually values for either hashmap keys or custom properties describing values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I settled on an extension to `String` that returns `NSPredicate`s. Much easier to get the raw string value.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, protocol extensions allow you to provide default implementations of code to conforming types. However, with enums you are probably better off writing one protocol and writing an extension to each enum to implement that protocol, like

```
extension ManagedItemProperties: ManagedProperty {
    func sortDescriptor(ascending: Bool = true) -> NSSortDescriptor {
        return NSSortDescriptor(key: ?????, ascending: ascending)
    }
    func predicateEqual(to arg: CVarArg) -> NSPredicate {
        return NSPredicate(format: "SELF.%@ == %@", ?????, arg)
    }
    func predicate(_ booleanValue: Bool) -> NSPredicate {
        return NSPredicate(format: "SELF.%@ == %d", ?????, booleanValue)
    }
}
```

If the predicates returned differ by the enum case, use a switch statement in your functions and Swift will make sure you include a code path for every case.